# Mongoose equivalent to "SELECT * FROM category where id <> parent_id;"

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a mysql table "category" with columns

**Column**
id
name
parent_id

I wanted to get records where *id* is not *parent_id*
SELECT * FROM category where id <> parent_id;

How can I perform the same operation with mongoose collection?

Comment: In case `parent_id` is a variable, then use `db.collection.find({ id: { $ne: parent_id } })`

Comment: No unfortunately it's not @Wernfried Domscheit. Both are fields from the same collection.

Comment: Then try `db.category.aggregate({ $match: { $expr: { $ne: ["$id", "$parent_id"] } } })`